# Git structure for resources changed at run-time?

Tags: git, maven

Right now we have a /resources (maven) directory which keeps files by product. When our code is deployed, these resources are loaded into the DB, so that at run-time product owners can change the content (thru custom UI).

An inherent problem with this, is that changes need to be reflected back into next releases. Having two sources of truth (git & DB) is problematic. Ideally, we could continue development as currently (with junits and all), but simplify this resource maintenance.

I was considering the possibility of using more git repos to address this, where product owners would simply use git as well. For permissions each product would need separate git repo, but I'd like these repos info somehow consolidated into our current /resources of our project.

My impression is that either a git subtree or subcomponent is appropriate here, and possibly there is also a maven component to this (consolidating?), but would appreciate advice on how to go about this, or if its not a good use of these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using submodules is a possibility, especially since all you need to do in your main repo is a git `submodule update  --recursive --remote` to update the submodules to the latest commit of the default `master` branch.

That means you don't have to use any special maven plugin, just running that command before your next build: your next release would then reflect the latest commits done by the products owner.